# bash commands from within python

Tags: python, bash

I'm looking for the best way to use bash commands from within python. What ways are there? I know of os.system and subprocess.Popen.

I have tried these:

```
bootfile = os.system("ls -l /jffs2/a.bin | cut -d '/' -f 4")
print bootfile
```

This returns a.bin as expected but also it retuns 0 afterwards and so prints:

```
a.bin
0
```

with bootfile now being set to 0. The next time I print bootfile it just shows up as 0. Which is the exit value I guess, how do i stop this value interfering?

I have also tried:

```
bootfile = subprocess.Popen("ls -l /jffs2/a.bin | cut -d '/' -f 4")
print bootfile
```

but it seems to break the script, as in I get nothing returned at all, have I done that right?

Also which of these is better and why? Are there other ways and what is the preferred way?

Comment: What is your goal with your bash commands ? I'm sure you could do this in python without calling bash.

Comment: Have you considered reading the documentation for `subprocess.Popen` at all?

Comment: I wish to return a symlink, this points to the name of the firmware. So in this case I want to return a.bin which will actually point to the name of the actual bin file

Comment: I am reading it now, I was using an example online and it seems it was terribly wrong.

Comment: @Paul so you want `os.readlink('/jffs2/a.bin')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `os.readlink` (proposed by @kojiro) and `os.path.basename` for getting only the namefile:

```
os.path.basename(os.readlink('/jffs2/a.bin'))
```

Comment: That's perfect thanks, now I want to know why popen returns none and I am satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

kojiro's comment about [`os.readlink`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.readlink) is probably what you want.
I am explaining what you were trying to implement.

[`os.system`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) would return you exit status of the command run.

[`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) will create a pipe, so that you can capture the output of the command run.
Below line will capture output of the command run:

```
bootfile = subprocess.Popen(["bash","-c","ls -l /jffs2/a.bin | cut -d '/' -f 4"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

More details at http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

Comment: That subprocess.Popen command won't work.  See the subprocess.Popen docs (in particular the "shell" parameter to Popen()).

Comment: thanks that's great, I jsut have to adjust it because instead of returning a.bin, it returns jffs2/a.bin and then none, setting the variable to none then.

Comment: I got it to return the binfile now, however it still returns "none" afterwards. You had changed the cut command for some reason :)

Answer (score 1):

The right answer, as @kojiro says, is:

```
os.readlink('/jffs2/a.bin')
```

But if you really wanted to do this the complicated way, then in Python 2.7:

```
cmd = "ls -l /jffs2/a.bin | cut -d '/' -f 4"
bootfile = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
```

Or on older Pythons:

```
cmd = "ls -l /jffs2/a.bin | cut -d '/' -f 4"
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
bootfile = p.communicate()[0]
if p.returncode != 0:
    raise Exception('It failed')
```

Comment: thanks for that, good to know different ways. My problem with popen is  bootfile = p.communicate[0] returns both the correct answer and then None after it.

Comment: I just fixed a typo... try p.communicate()[0].  (p.communicate() returns a tuple, the [0] bit takes the first element from that tuple).

Comment: Hi, I had fixed your typo myself thanks, I should have mentioned that. The thing is, when I am accessing index 0 it is giving me the correct value and none also, then marking the variable as none. Which makes no sense to me. I did it another way but not knowing why bothers me :)